# How to present the contents of an Activity to a virtual display?

Tags: mediarecorder, android-virtualdisplay

I have an activity and the contents of it needs to be rendered to a virtual display created via createVirtualDisplay, where I pass a surface to get rendered to.

I'm trying to find a way to get the contents of the main activity to the surface passed to the virtual display.

Note: I don't want to use MediaProjection API as I want to render the single activity alone but not complete screen on the surface passed to Virtual Display.